# Java: How do I close a JFrame while opening another one?

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans-6.9

My program starts with a picture with a textfield in a JFrame. I want when the user types start it closes the picture JFrame and opens another JFrame with the main program. I've tried

`processEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`

on the Image frame but it closes all the windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method `JFrame.setVisible` can be used to hide or display the JFrame based on the arguments, while `JFrame.dispose` will actually "destroy" the frame, by closing it and freeing up resources that it used. Here, you would call `setVisible(false)` on the picture frame if you intend to reopen it, or call `dispose()` on the picture frame if you will not be opening it again, so your program can free some memory. Then you would call `setVisible(true)` on the main frame to make it visible.

Answer (score 3):

you also can use this code

for example

```
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you set the picture JFrame's [default close operation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) to something besides `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, perhaps `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, you can prevent your application from closing before the second JFrame appears.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String userName =  textField.getText();
    String password = textField_1.getText();
    if(userName.equals("mgm") &&  password.equals("12345")) {            
         secondFrame nF = new secondFrame();

         nF.setVisible(false);
         dispose();          
    }   
    else 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Wrong password ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing and found that using "this" is the best and easiest option.
you can Use the following code:
`this.dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old but nevertheless.

If you initialize the form like that:

```
JFrame firstForm = new JFrame();

firstForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
firstForm.setSize(800, 600);
firstForm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

firstForm.setVisible(true);
```

And for instance create or open another form by a button:

```
JFrame secondForm = new JFrame();

secondForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
secondForm.setSize(800, 600);
secondForm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

secondForm.setVisible(true);

this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

This will dispose and destroy the first window without exiting the program.
The key is to set `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`.
It also raises the events (I've tested it with the `WindowClosing` event).

Answer (score 1):

For netbeans use the reference of the current Object and `setVisible(false);`
for example

```
private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    this.setVisible(false);//Closing the Current frame
    new login().setVisible(true);// Opening a new frame
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use this :

```
opens_frame frameOld= new opens_frame();
            frameOld.setVisible(true);
            Closing_Frame.setVisible(false);
            Closing_Frame.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void closeTheCurrentFrameAndOpenNew(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

 dispose();//To close the current window

 YourClassName closeCurrentWindow = new YourClassName();
 closeCurrentWindow.setVisible(true);//Open the new window

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First call it

```
new Window().nextjframe.setVisible(true);
thisjframe.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(username.equals("gaffar")&&password.equals("12345"))
    {
    label.setText("Be ready to continue");
    //Start of 2nd jframe
    NewJFrame1 n=new NewJFrame1();
     n.setVisible(true);
     //Stop code for ist jframe
     NewJFrame m=new NewJFrame();
     m.setVisible(false);
     dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what i came up for opening a new jframe while closing the other one:

```java
JFrame CreateAccountGUI = new JFrame();
CreateAccountGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
CreateAccountGUI.setSize(800, 600);
CreateAccountGUI.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
CreateAccountGUI.setVisible(true);   
this.setVisible(false);
```